# Corollary to Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, predicate-logic, congruences

A consequence of Fermat's Little Theorem

> > If $p$ is prime and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ not divisible by $p$, $a^{p-1} \equiv_{p} 1 $

is

> > If $p$ is prime and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $a^{p} \equiv_{p} a$  $\quad*\mathbb{\S}*$

The contrapositive of this statement can be used to test for primality:

[image]

---

I am having trouble accepting the statement above as the contrapositive, from a purely "mechanical" point of view - i.e the statement is logically true to me but the manipulation of quantifiers to obtain the contrapositive doesn't seem true.

My trouble most likely lies in the following distinction:

What is the difference between these two statements:

> > $\forall p \in \mathbb{N}$, $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $p$ is prime, then $a^{p} \equiv a$ mod $p$.
> >
> > $\forall p \in \mathbb{N}$, if $p$ is prime, then $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$ $a^{p} \equiv a$ mod $p$.(2)

I believe that the second is a correct, formal rendering of $\mathbb{\S}$. It also leads to the contrapositive. But why does the first not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the contraposive of   $\forall p,  A(p) \implies B(p)$ inside the $\forall p$, you have $\forall p, \neg B(p) \implies \neg A(p) $

If you take $A$ : "p is prime"; $B$ : "$\forall a \in \mathbb{N}, a^p \equiv_p a $", you have $\neg B $: $\exists a \in \mathbb{N}, a^p \not\equiv_p a $ which implies "p is not prime"

Comment: So the second statement is correct. But why is the first wrong? The pairs $(p, a)$ are exactly the same in both cases, aren't they?

Comment: Both statements are correct. You can invert the parts "$\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$" and "$p$ is prime", both statements are equivalent. However, the contraposive won't be the same (although it will also be equivalent). I suggest you look a little into first order logic calculus, it is very interesting.